# Trouble populating 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I'm trying to populate a 2d array in java for a sudoku board. The numbers come from a csv file. The issue is the code just reads the first four numbers, then restarts at 0 again for a new row. How do I stop this from happening, and get it to continue to the end of the numbers?

```
    String[] lines = Cell.toCSV().split(",");
    int[] intArray = new int[lines.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(lines[i]);
    } //convert string to int

    int[][] dataArray = new int[4][4]; //4x4 sudoku game

    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < dataArray[col].length; row++) {
            dataArray[col][row] = intArray[row];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate counter for the original array :

```
int index = 0;
for (int col = 0; col < dataArray.length; col++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < dataArray[col].length; row++) {
        dataArray[col][row] = intArray[index++];
}
```

This is assuming the `intArray` has enough values to populate the 2D array. You should probably validate that prior to this loop.

BTW, the first dimension of a 2D array is usually considered as the row, not the column, so your loop variable names are a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution :)